# Importing Bootstrap 4 tags input with webpack and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, bootstrap-4, yarnpkg

I am following [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Bootstrap-4-Tag-Input-Plugin-jQuery.html) document and trying to grab the tag input functionality in my rails application using webpack.

I added the following line 
`import 'tagsinput.js'`
to import this library in my `application.js` file but performing a `yarn install` didn't seem to recognize the library.

I am guessing I am importing it the wrong way or either not initializing it in webpack config. Looking for help on the right way to import and use this library using yarn and webpack.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get [bootstrap4-tagsinput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap4-tagsinput) working in my Rails app for `webpacker` by:

**A)** Adding `bootstrap4-tagsinput` module via `Yarn`

```
yarn add bootstrap4-tagsinput
```

**B)** Importing the `bootstrap4-tagsinput` into my `application.js`

```
import 'bootstrap4-tagsinput/tagsinput.js'
```

**C)** Importing stylesheet into my main `scss` file

```
@import "~bootstrap4-tagsinput/tagsinput";
```

Here's what it looks like in my app:

[image: bootstrap4-tagsinput example]

Answer (score 0):

Harumpf. This only shows up with tags if I refresh the form. It seems to run too early.